# How to add device metrics to the Eclipse ADT WSIWYG Layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have quite a few Android devices, of pretty much all sizes and densities. One of these devices is an Asus Transformer, which has a 1920x1200 resolution.

The Generic device previews in the Graphical Layout of my XML file only go up to 720p devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab, etc).

Is there a way that I can add a resolution to Eclipse/ADT ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

If so, use the AVD manager and select the *Device Definitions* tab.  Then, click the *New Device...* button.  Your new device will show up under "User" in the menu.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I never noticed that tab before, even though I've setup AVD's .... Cheers!